# How to modify an exported variable from child

Tags: bash

I have a lot of bash scripts that work on an exported variable called WORKING_FILE.

This variable is exported in the main.sh script which is the first script launched in a shell and during his execution it calls other scripts (e. g. child.sh).

Actually, child.sh see the WORKING_FILE as a copy of the main.sh environment and if it tries to change the WORKING_FILE the value will be lost at the end of its execution.

So, the question is:
how can child.sh modify the value of WORKING_FILE and change the WORKING_FILE value also in the main.sh without using files?

Thanks. :)

Comment: you cannot, in general, modify parent environment from child.
Perhaps you want to `source` the child script.

Comment: One way to achieve this effect would be to put the value of $WORKING_FILE in a temp file, set WORKING_FILE to the path of the temp file, and then change the contents of the temp file when needed.

Comment: Alternatively, you can have the child output the new value to a known FD, read that FD in the parent via redirection, and change the parent's copy of the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you export the variable and execute the child, then you cannot -- the child gets a *copy* of the variable, and any changes are not visible in the parent.

You can, however, *source* the script,

```
. ./child.sh
```

or

```
source child.sh
```

This will execute the child script in the same interpreter and any changes to the environment this script makes will be visible in your script.